# How to access sheets from xlwings after ignoring links?

Tags: python, xlwings

I’m not able to open any sheets after ignoring links.

```
Import xlwings as xw
App = xw.App(visible=False)
Path = ‘P:\\my_name\\fx_risk_pack’
App.display_alerts= False

WB= App.books.api.Open(path, updatelinks=False)
```

It connects but then I’m having trouble accessing the worksheets?

```
Sheet= WB.Sheets(“sheet1”)
Sheet.range(“A1”).expand(“down”).address
```

Gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind figured it out.

```
App = xw.app(visible=False)
App.display_alerts= False
Book = xw.Book(path)
```

Where path is one I gave above.  This works for python 3